# VBA to Auto Fill Specific Number of Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to autofill a specific number of rows in a column based on a number found in another cell (which changes based on data)

So say cell **D2 = 250**

I need to label FF4:FF**250** with numbers 1,2,3,4,5... so that it looks like this

```
       Column FF
Cell 4    1
Cell 5    2
Cell 6    3
Cell 7    4
 ...     ...
```

I'm playing around with something like this but it doesn't work

```
Sub AutoFillSpecific()

    MyValue = Range("D2").Value
    Range("FF4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(FF4:FFMyValue)
```

Any help?

Comment: Unsure, it looks like a solid question @user3682157...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a value in `FF4` to autofill down:

```
Range("FF4").Value = 1
Range("FF4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("FF4:FF" & MyValue), Type:=xlFillSeries
```

You'll want to add `Dim MyValue As Long` to avoid errors because it will make sure the value of D2 is a number when you move it into the `MyValue`.

Comment: Use `Long` rather than Integer

Comment: Happy now @chrisneilsen?

Comment: ahh was just missing that & sign -- so one question I have is that the value in FF4 is "1" and using this macro, it just autifills the entire columns with one.  Perhaps I should have been more clear, I need it to read 1,2,3,4,etc...