# Auto-fill numbering in a column of Excel based on the value of another column dynamically

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Firstly, let me try to explain what it is I'm trying to accomplish (lest anyone has any better suggestions).

I have a set of data that will come to me with any number of rows and values each month. Without the ability to be specific, I'll come up with a general example: Let's say these are people looking for jobs, so the data will change every month. In this dataset, I have a flag that indicates whether or not they're "interested" in the specific job I'm hiring for (again, this is a fake example, so I'm sure there are tools that actually do this, just go with it). I am only allowed to take a certain percentage of the entire pool of applicants and I want to take that percentage from only the "interested" parties, but the count of "interested" parties are greater than that percentage. Let's say my total number of people is 100000 and the interested number is 7000, but I can only take 2% of the total population.

So, I created a cell that gives me what the 2% is. I figured that I would try to auto-fill a line number only on the rows where the "Interested" flag is "Yes" (all other rows would be 0 or N/A) and, when the auto-fill gets to be the same number as my fixed cell giving my 2% (2000), then it stops filling in the numbers (or makes them 0 or N/A - whatever). Then I can filter by that column.

I can do VBA or formula or whatever you can think of, I just don't know how to accomplish this.

For reference, this article seemed to be very close, but didn't have the specified reference to a value from another column: [VBA to Auto Fill Specific Number of Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828504/vba-to-auto-fill-specific-number-of-rows)

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but may help.

```
Dim RwNum As Integer
Dim lCol As Integer

lCol = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

RwNum = Range("Ref Cell") 'the cell that gives you the 2%

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=x, Criteria1:="Yes", Operator:=xlFilterValues 'Field "x" is the "Yes" column

Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(RwNum, lCol)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheetx").Range("A1") 'sheetx would be a blank worksheet; this will give you a listing of the 2%.
```

Comment: Thanks. I got a bit side-tracked, but I'll try to test within the week and let you know how it goes.